# ¿Cómo obtener la cantidad de una columna en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Hola tengo una consulta en la que necesito obtener la cantidad de personas que tienen sesiones mayores a 2

este es mi consulta llego a obtener la cantidad de  personas que tiene sesiones mayores a 2 pero no se como contar esa columna

```
select nombre  as PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos , 
       count(*) Sesiones from ong_padma.sesiones 
inner join paciente 
    on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino' 
and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1 
group by nombre  
having count(cantidad_sesiones)>2;

________________________________________________
|PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos |CantidadSesiones |
| ---------------------------| ------------    | 
|  Alex                      |  10             |
|  Jose                      |  8              |
|  Maria                     |  5              |
|  Jose                      |  4              |
```

pero necesito contar la columna resultante (PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos) y que me quede esta manera

```
______________________________
|PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos |
| ---------------------------|
|  4                         |
```

Answer (score 3):

Usa todo eso como una subconsulta:

```
select count(*) from
(
    select nombre  as PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos , 
           count(*) Sesiones from ong_padma.sesiones 
    inner join paciente 
        on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
    where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino' 
    and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1 
    group by nombre  
    having count(cantidad_sesiones)>2
)
```

Comment: me resulta esto  Código de error: 1064. Tiene un error en su sintaxis SQL; consulte el manual que corresponde a la versión de su servidor MariaDB para conocer la sintaxis correcta para usar cerca de 'LIMIT 0, 1000' en la línea 12

Comment: `select count(*) as cantidad from
(
    select nombre  as PacienteSesionesMayoresAdos , 
           count(*) Sesiones from ong_padma.sesiones 
    inner join paciente 
        on paciente.ID_numero_historia = sesiones.ID_numero_historia
    where paciente.Genero = 'Masculino' 
    and paciente.ID_Etapa_Vital = 1 
    group by nombre  
    having count(cantidad_sesiones)>2
) paciente 
`         gracias